# How to get the local timezone given time and state info

Tags: python, sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

I am using a combination of `Python` and `Amazon Redshift`.
I have hits from various users and some data around those hits. This may be visualized in the following format:

```
UTCTime    State    IP    Country
<time>    CA    10.1.1.1    US
<time>    AZ    10.1.1.2    US
<time>    NY    10.1.1.3    US
```

I would like to convert this UTC time to the local time, as the above hits are from various time zones. There's a function in `Amazon Redshift`:

```
CONVERT_TIMEZONE ( ['source_timezone',] 'target_timezone', 'timestamp')
```

But this requires `Target timezone`. How do I find this target timezone given this info.

If there's any other way to do this, I will be happy to know that too.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no easy answer to this, since while it's true that most US States exist in only one time zone, it's not true of all states (OR, ID, ND, SD, NE, KS, MI, IN, KY, TN, TX, and FL observe multiple time zones).  Further complicating the issue is that some states (Arizona) don't observe Daylight Savings Time, but the rest do, and the target timezone offset for a given state will differ based on whether or not the given timestamp falls in Standard Time, or DST.

Answer (score 7):

You could approach this problem by using [us](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/us) package. Add it via pip:

```
$ pip install us
```

> The state lookup method allows matching by FIPS code, abbreviation, and name:

```
>>> us.states.lookup('24')
<State:Maryland>
>>> us.states.lookup('MD')
<State:Maryland>
>>> us.states.lookup('md')
<State:Maryland>
>>> us.states.lookup('maryland')
<State:Maryland>
```

as mentioned in us package description, `State` object has `time_zones` and `capital_tz` attributes, which names are self explanitory:

```
>>> us.states.lookup('MD').capital_tz
'America/New_York'
```

and

```
>>> us.states.lookup('MD').time_zones
['America/New_York']
```

Now you can easily translate state abbreviation to full time zone name.