# Converting State IDs to Time Zones

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create a column of time zones from a column of state abbreviations from a pandas dataframe. [I used basically the exact same code as was discussed in this previous question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661041/how-to-get-the-local-timezone-given-time-and-state-info), and am trying to use this code.

```
df['Time_Zone'] = us.states.lookup(df['Event_State'])
```

However, I either get the following error when running my code...

```
  File "c:\[path to my file]\myfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    df['Time_Zone'] = us.states.lookup(df['Event_State'])
  File "C:\[path to my file]\myfile.py", line 80, in lookup
    if FIPS_RE.match(val):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

...or, when I edit it to `str(df['Event_State'])`, my dataframe comes out as the following.

```
       Event_State Time_Zone
0              nan      None
1              nan      None
2              nan      None
3              nan      None
4              nan      None
...            ...       ...
25546           FL      None
25547           ID      None
25548           AZ      None
25549           TX      None
25550           CA      None
```

Is there a reason why I cannot get ANY timezone appended into my dataframe? Any assistance is truly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

make sure df['Event_State'] is string not None value

Comment: I've tried everything when it come to making ```df['Event_State']``` into a string and I always find a way to get those same two errors. I constantly have df.info pop up and I always have both Event_State and Time_Zone generated as ```25551 non-null object``` even with all these commands asking them to become strings.